# CSS Additional Pseudo Elements to One Class (before, after, +more)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve the below result by ONLY using the "labels" class (eg. I don't want the "arrow" class/html). Is this possible with pseudo elements only? Like ".labels:tesing{}" etc.

```
.labels{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}

.labels:before{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 12px;
    content: '$';
}

.labels:after{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    content: 'USD';
}


.arrow{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="labels">199
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/edcxsw1/w9z7vvxw/

Comment: The $ and the USD text are part of the content, and you should have that in your content, not in the CSS.  And then you'll have the pseudo-elements freed up to use for triangles.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with CSS only, but pretty simple with jQuery. Just that way:

```
$('.labels').append('<div class="arrow"></div>');
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/w9z7vvxw/3/